# Find the minimum and maximum values of y in $4x^2 + 12xy + 10y^2 – 4y + 3 = 0$

Tags: derivatives, optimization, quadratics, maxima-minima

Find the minimum and maximum values of y in $4x^2 + 12xy + 10y^2 – 4y + 3 = 0.$

$$4x^2 + 12xy + 10y^2 – 4y + 3 = 0$$
$$(2x+3y)^2 +(y-2)^2=1$$
$$y_{max}=3$$
$$y_{min}=1$$

Any other approach for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need $$\Delta_x\geq0$$ or
$$36y^2-4(10y^2-4y+3)\geq0$$ or
$$(y-1)(y-3)\leq0$$ or
$$1\leq y\leq3,$$which gives the answer because easy to show that the equality occurs in both cases.

Comment: What is  $$\Delta_x\geq0$$

Comment: For $ax^2+bx+c,$ where $a\neq0$ we have: $\Delta_x=b^2-4ac.$

Comment: Why the discriminant is greater than zero

Comment: @Abhishek Kumar Because a quadratic equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$ has real roots.

Answer (score 1):

Differentiating with respect to $x$ gives $$8x+12y=0$$
We already have $$4x^2 + 12xy + 10y^2 – 4y + 3 = 0 \rightarrow (2x+3y)^2+(y-2)^2=1$$

Both of these must be satisfied in order to find the extrema. Solving for $x$ in the first equality finds $$x = -\frac{3y}{2}$$

Plugging this into the second equation finds $$\left(-3y+3y\right)^2+(y-2)^2=1 \rightarrow (y-2)^2=1 \rightarrow y-2 = \pm 1$$

Finally, we have that $y = 1, 3$ are the minimum and maximum values of $y$ for this equation.

Answer (score 1):

Implicit differentiation of $$4x^2 + 12xy + 10y^2 – 4y + 3 = 0$$

with respect to $x$ implies $$ y'= \frac {-8x-12y}{12x+20y-4}$$

The maximum and minimum points are found by $y'=0$ which implies $$2x+3y=0$$

Since  $$4x^2 + 12xy + 10y^2 – 4y + 3 = 0 \implies (2x+3y)^2 +y^2-4y+3=0$$

We get $$y^2-4y +3 =0 $$ that is $y=1$ for the minimum and  $y=3$ for the maximum.